# How do I sort the java.security.AccessControlException issue when running rmi programs?

Tags: java, security, rmi, policy

How do I sort the  java.security.AccessControlException problem? When I am running the myRMIServer,I am getting this exception?

My codes:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class myRMIServer
{
        public static void main(String[] argv)
                {
                System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
                try
                        {
                        myRMIImpl implementation = new myRMIImpl("myRMIImplInstance");
                        }
                catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
                        }
                }
}
```

---

```
public interface myRMIInterface extends java.rmi.Remote
{
        public java.util.Date getDate() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

---

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class myRMIImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements myRMIInterface
{
        public myRMIImpl(String name) throws RemoteException
                {
                super();
                try
                        {
                        Naming.rebind(name, this);
                        }
                catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
                        }
                }
        public java.util.Date getDate()
                {
                return new java.util.Date();
                }
}
```

Output

```
Exception occurred: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a .policy file that grants the required permissions, and name it in a java.security.policy argument.

Or get rid of the security manager. It's only required if you are using the RMI codebase feature.